# Custom field background fallback image

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-fields, advanced-custom-fields

I'm using a custom field to show a different background on every page of my wordpress blog like this:

```
<div id="wrapper" style="background-image: url('<?php the_field('background'); ?>');">
```

But now i'd like to have a **fallback** image for when their is no image is set.

Anybody knows how to do this?

thnx in advance

Comment: Consider a ternary operator.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ACF Header Background](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31117074/acf-header-background)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15439674/adding-a-fallback-image-to-a-wordpress-advanced-custom-fields-loop

Comment: both solutions didn't work for me

Comment: There's no reason why (at the very least) the first solution shouldn't work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your code is inside the loop

```
<?php if(isset(get_field('background'))){?>
<div id="wrapper" style="background-image: url('<?php the_field('background'); ?>');
<?php } else{?>
<div id="wrapper" style="background-image: url('any_custom_image_path');

<?php }?>
```

Comment: `<?php if(get_field('background')){?>` works too. Personally I like to make an option page for global defaults and fallbacks so the user can enter their own fallback image.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this as your inline CSS:
<?php
    $ACFimg = get_field('yourimagefieldname');
    $default_img = anything.jpg; (the image you want to show if user do not put any)
?>

<div style="background-image:url(<?php echo (!empty ( $ACFimg )? $ACFimg['url']: $default_img ); ?>);" ></div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).